# Where's the head on an Atlantean jumper?

Tags: spaceship, stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

On several *Stargate Atlantis* and late *Stargate SG-1* episodes they spend a very long time on a jumper.   For example, in *Atlantis* 4x17 "Midway", at the end, Bill Lee, Kavanagh, McKay and Shepard are on a gateship for more than a day

> after Midway is destroyed until the Daedalus picks them up in intergalactic space

But there's no apparently place for a head (toilet).

I'm familiar with Nobody Poops (not putting TVTropes link as a public service), but this is a little different because usually you can imagine it is somewhere but not seen.   In a jumper, there is literally no place for it.    Because of this unique case, and *Stargate*'s propensity to break the fourth wall, I'm wondering if there's anything out there.

Any discussion by show personnel or any canon information?   And I'll even just take a tongue-in-cheek "Man's I gotta take a leak real bad" when someone returns to Atlantis.

Comment: Maybe it was more of the magical technologies that could just  pop out of the floor or was built into one of the seats

Comment: Can't find any cannon. But someone else had similar thoughts [here.](http://archiveofourown.org/works/2181141) "It’s in the back cabin and it’s nearly exactly like the fold out throne found on the C-130 Hercules, without the benefit of the shower cubicle privacy screen. Oh, and this one vents to space."

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive given the graphic from the MGM website. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: The Ancients had very advanced biomedical technology. Even without the ATA gene that would allow an individual the full breadth of the Ancients wonders, the human genome, and its biological functions, is easily understandable by the control computers of the Ancients. I suspect that waste from biological functions are simply teleported into space, as the human body generates it - users may not even notice the process, so advanced were the Ancients.

Comment: @PhasedOut  - Ah yes, the old teleporting poo hypothesis

Comment: @PhasedOut - all quite possible, but I can't help but ponder the fate of the folks without the Ancient Technology Activation (ATA) gene.  Ancient tech, and one assumes any bio waste razzle-dazzle, requires the ATA.  ("Colonel Shephard, could you please activate the loo?"  "Again?  Man, what did you eat?")

Answer (score 12):

MGM Posted a series of [schematics](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/MGM_Tech_Journal) on their official SGA website.

As you can see from the image below, the puddle-jumper (AKA Gateship) isn't equipped with a toilet.

[image: Puddle Jumper Schematics]

As to where people poop, I strongly suspect that they would have relied on [advanced Terran technology](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TravelJohn-Disposable-Urinal-Bag-3-Pack/dp/B003U2T6AU).